# How to migrate from xml files to programmatic configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this class from where the app starts:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainCore extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(MainCore.class, args);
    }

}
```

And those two XML files:

web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID"
         version="4.0">

    <display-name>Fooname</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fooname</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fooname</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

fooname-servlet.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.web.fooname.controller" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

</beans>
```

And I want to remove those 2 files and transform them to code.

Someone can help me with this? I know this is not the purpose of Stack Overflow, but I have read a lot of tutorials but don't understand them.

Comment: Remove web.xml. Place your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in `com.web.fooname` (you still need a proper `configure` method if you plan on deploying this as a war BTW. Add `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` and `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/` to your `application.properties` file. Remove your `fooname-servlet.xml` and start your application.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I'm deploying as a WAR. Just these 3 things are enough? And how remain with resources mapping?

Comment: And the proper `configure` method else it won't start. If you really need the additional mapping (not sure if that is already a default, as I forgot :s). You can add a class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer` and implement the `addResourceHandler` method to register this mapping.

Comment: I finally got it. Thank you.